# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB for different schemas

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to query different schemas/users in an ASP.NET Web Application. As soon as a statement is executed for certain schemas I get an ORA-00932 CLOB error even though the statement has nothing to do with a CLOB. The statements work fine in Visual Studio but fail on an actual IIS. Can someone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: Welcome! If you want something more than mere guesses; you may share the database structure and the code for that very statement fails.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tab` and some column has CLOB datatype?

Comment: There is no CLOB datatype in the table and the statement is basically select * from table where id = x. The database has several schemas and statements for some of them seem to fail. The code als executes a SET ROLE ... statement before the actual statement.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a mission section in the web.config.

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```